# D3D Примитив с текстурой.

Tags: directx, opengl

Вопрос, есть ли в DX нечто подобное опенжлевским glVertex3, glTextCord, текстура меню хранится 1 файлом, нужно из него куски вырезать и использовать как текстуру, в опенжле просто задавались координаты на текстуре....
Если можно простой пример подобного кода только на DX...

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Skin);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  //Midlle
  glTexCoord2f(009/128  ,096/128); glVertex2f(0         ,0);
  glTexCoord2f(009/128  ,064/128); glVertex2f(0         ,Height);
  glTexCoord2f(039/128  ,064/128); glVertex2f(Width     ,Height);
  glTexCoord2f(039/128  ,096/128); glVertex2f(Width     ,0);
  //......
glend;
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, рисую из дллки в чужом приложении, вся отрисовка ведется перед EndScene;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так полагаю, вам нужен фиксированный конвейер ? В случае фиксированного вы должны использовать DX9. В старших версиях он не поддерживается и способ задания формата очень похож но другой. 
Вот пример для DX9 :

Этот код описывает формат вершины который будет прикручиваться к фиксированному конвейеру

```
#define FVF_VERTEX_TEX D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX1
```

Создаете далее такую структуру :

```
struct Vertex
{
    float vx, vy, vz;
    float tx, ty
};
```

Далее создаете свой массив с вышеприведенными данными где каждый элемент это Vertex. 
Отрисовка квадратов не поддерживается. Можете задать

```
D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST или D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN

START_VERTEX и PRIMITIVE_COUNT определите сами
```

Отрисовка происходит так :

```
      Device->Clear(0, 0,
            D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
            0xffffffff, 1.0f, 0);
      Device->BeginScene();

      Device->SetStreamSource(0, VB, 0, sizeof(Vertex));
      Device->SetFVF(Vertex::FVF);
      Device->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, START_VERTEX, PRIMITIVE_COUNT);

      Device->EndScene();
      Device->Present(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Да, и если вы не будете задавать нормали в формате то отключите конвейерное освещение иначе у вас быстрее всего будет черная текстура.

```
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, false);
```

Comment: Спасиб, за код, расписано понятно, а то по примерам нагугленым несовсем понимал что и где происходит, единственный вопрос....

    #define FVF_VERTEX_TEX D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX1 

как сие записать в паскалях....(или что использовать вместо этого)
и да, DX8 и(или) 9, зависит от того что использует приложение у меня оверлэйная библиотека :)

Comment: Вопрос снимается :) 
     
     Const
       FVF_VERTEX_TEX = D3DFVF_XYZ or D3DFVF_TEX1;